# Can't create app for paypal REST API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've signed in to the developer website but when I go to the apps page to create my app I see the following error message:

```
Problem creating sandbox facilitator account [Error code: 2001]
```

When I look on the sandbox accounts page I see there is a facilitator account there (xxx-facilitator@xxxx.xxx)

When I click the "create app" button the "sandbox developer account" dropdown is empty and when I try to create an app I get the following error message:

```
We’re sorry, but something went wrong while creating the application. Please try again.
```

So far I've:

1. created new sandbox users
2. submitted a query to paypal's tech support (no response)
3. left it a day and tried again
4. logged in, logged out...

Comment: Really ridiculous. Those guys do not bother to provide any meaningful explanation of the error they throw. Very unprofessional. I'm experiencing the same issue in June 2016!

Comment: Updated workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40055467/cant-create-paypal-rest-app-missing-sandbox-developer-account

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem. The "Sandbox developer account" dropdown box had no entries although I had set up accounts before - so I couldn't create an app.
After some trial and error hacking I finally found a way to inject a valid option in the html select and successfully created the app in the end.

Here's how:

Log in to your developer.paypal.com profile and go to Sandbox - Accounts.

Just use Firebug in Firefox or Developer Tools in Chrome to examine the source: Check the source of your BUSINESS account and you will find a code line like this:

```
<a class="profile" target="/developer/accounts/detail/2297102045097598612">Profile</a>
```

Note the id (e.g. 2297102045097598612), the country code (e.g. US) and the email address.

Now go to Dashboard - My Apps & Credentials and press "Create app"

Open Firebug/Dev. Tools and examine the "Sandbox developer account" dropdown box. Right-Click the empty select in the dom and choose "Edit as HTML". Enter an option tag with your formerly noted values, just like this:

```
<option value="2297102045097598612,email@domain.com">email@domain.com (US)</option>
```

Check that the option now appears in the dropdown box.

Enter a name in the "App name" field and press "Create app".

That's it. Hope I could help.

Comment: This works! All you need is a valid ID and E-Mail for a sandbox account to generate credentials. I was able to use the default sandbox business/facilitator account, then created my app successfully, and it gave me the API credentials I needed on the next page like it was supposed to.

Comment: It worked for me too, a huge thanks. Unbelievable that's the way to do it on a platform supposed to be secure..

Comment: Thank you! Why is it I observe a consistent pattern of unreliability with corporate networks? The eBay Sandbox is absolutely diabolical, and the PayPal Sandbox isn't far off. Solely subscribing to the philosophy of financially driven development isn't good for business. You're just slowing digging yourself a hole that's going to get harder and harder to get out of.

Comment: The issue still here. Thanks for your solution it worked for me!

Comment: I'm getting 'Bad request' when I press 'Create app'

Answer (score 2):

I got the 'Problem creating sandbox facilitator account' error as well but it was with a different error code of 'TAGETLIST404-20141017053750'. Obviously the suffix is just a timestamp.

The problem seemed to have been caused by the Oauth login popup that initially returned a timeouted session error but appeared to have still logged in anyway as it showed my name in the topright corner. But trying to create new apps returned the sandbox facilitator error.

Clearing cookies and logging in again, not getting the timeout error seemed to fix it and I could create accounts. I know this isn't a great answer but it's something to try.

Comment: This worked for me.  Actually I just started a new "private browsing" or "incognito" browser window, logged into the paypal developer console again, and then I was able to see my created apps, create new ones, and edit the existing ones. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I waited two days, and the error messages regarding the facilitator account went away.  I was then able to make a new business account.  This then allowed me to create a REST app without error.

Comment: This is not properly an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by just editing the source a bit.

Right click on the dropdown for your account if it's empty and click on Inspect element in your browser.
Inside the  tags for the dropdown, add your email in  tags. The email should be of a valid sandbox account that you had created.

For example, if you'd like to add a sandbox account with the email business@example.com, 
add business@example.com within the select tags.

Seems like it's something easily fixable from Paypal's side but they haven't bothered fixing it yet.

Comment: hmm did that buy adding an option tag, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

for PayFlow API -  allow up to 3 hours for the change to go into effect.after 3 hours it saved data while clicking.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my primary email account was not confirm. after confirm it allow me

Answer (score 0):

Today, I've just encoutered the same error with you. The problem is how Paypal raise the error, which made us very confuse. The error they should raise is: " You have not created any developer account yet, create an account and try again".

And here is how I fix it:

1. Go to: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts
2. Create a **BUSINESS** sandbox account.
3. Go back and try create app again to see if it work.