# PayPal Dev: Cannot create an App / empty Sandbox field

Tags: api, paypal, sandbox

I cannot crate an App, because the field for the sandbox user is always empty. I created a sandbox account, but it's not showing in the "Sandbox developer account" field.

Is this a PayPal related problem, or am I not creating sandbox accounts correctly?

Comment: Check out this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/34923626/1483977