# Cannot create app - Paypal

Tags: paypal

So i'm trying to create a new paypal app but none of my accounts get recognized when creating it.

I have two accounts I made (business and personal account).

[image]

Whenever I go to create the app, I get this error.

[image]

Any help is appreciates, i'm preatty new to this. Thanks!

Comment: found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504445/cant-create-app-for-paypal-rest-api