# Can't create paypal rest app, missing sandbox developer account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

On the create app page I can't proceed as the dropdown of the sandbox developer account appeared blank to me:

[image]

But I already have sandbox accounts:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/soXLN.jpg

Is this a bug or what? It's confusing.

Comment: Hi Thian - it should at least show for the business account; probably a bug. However try to upgrade the account to a pro account and try again. If t doesn't work then contact the PaPal tech team @ paypal.com/mts , contact support link at the bottom. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of forcing users to upgrading to Pro account with $30/month.
I've found a work around different from old suggestion: [Can't create app for paypal REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504445/cant-create-app-for-paypal-rest-api), it doesn't work anymore, looks like paypal have fixed this hack instead of fixing the actual issue :(

1. Login to your paypal business account.
2. Go to developer.paypal.com then Sandbox -> Accounts.
3. Create a BUYER account, please make sure this is BUYER account.
4. Click on 'log in with Paypal', and login with credentials you created at step #3.
5. It will ask for permission, click yes, and it will show that the account has been linked to another developer. Never mind, because it was linked to your account already. This is really bullshit message!
6. Go back to Sandbox -> Accounts and expand your newly created account, click on Profile.
7. Make sure the popup contains information, if it just shows 'Your request is still processing...', then it means you were not lucky enough. Try to create another account from step #3. Do no try to go next step or it just wastes your time.
8. Go to sandbox.paypal.com and login with your newly created account.
9. Upgrade this account to business account. There will be a few steps of asking something, go ahead faking anything, the last step to update security number won't be success, never mind.
10. Go back to sandbox.paypal.com and make sure that account have merchant ID.
11. Verify step #6 & #7 again.
12. Now go ahead with creating your Rest Application.

@Paypal developers! I think you guys need to fix the actual issue instead of trying to fix these hacks.

Comment: I've got a really bad experience while making a demo app with paypal !! :/